# Hash Table implement iterate and findMin

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have coded a standard Hash Table class in java. It has a large array of buckets, and to insert, retrieve or delete elements, I simply calculate the hash of the element and look at the appropriate index in the array to get the right bucket.

However, I would like to implement some sort of iterator. Is there an other way than looping through all the indices in the array and ignoring those that are empty? Because my hash table might contain hundreds of empty entries, and only a few elements that have been hashed and inserted. Is there a O(n) way to iterate instead of O(size of table) when n<<size of table?

To implement findMin, I could simply save the smallest element each time I insert a new one, but I want to use the iterator approach.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need an iterator, then perhaps a new design is called for. Maybe a list instead of a sparse array? The default java implementation uses a map (dictionary). That has many advantages.

Comment: I just made this implementation to understand my data structures course better. I am not looking for an already made implementation that would undoubtedly speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a linked list of the map entries, like LinkedHashMap does in the standard library.

Or you can make your hash table ensure that the capacity is always at most kn, for some suitable value of k. This will ensure iteration is linear in n.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a sorted list of the non-empty buckets, and insert a bucket's id into the list (if it's not already there) when you insert something in the hash table.

But maybe it's not too expensive to search through a few hundred empty buckets, if it's not buried too deep inside a loop.  A little inefficiency might be better than a more complex design.

Answer (score 0):

If order is important to you you should consider using a Binary Search Tree (a left leaning red black tree for example) or a Skip List to implement your Dictionary. They are better for the job in these cases.